# How to send regex expression from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, ajax

I try to send the regular expression `\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+\+\d+:\d+\sINFO\s\(\d\):\sSTARTE\sKundenimport` to my PHP webserver.

So I tried to Base64 encode the string before sending it. `Base64.encode(startRegex)`

```
function test(logfile, startRegex, endRegex)
{
    return $.ajax({
       url: "ajax.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {
           action: "getAllStrBetween",
           inputStr: logfile,
           startRegex: Base64.encode(startRegex),
           endRegex: Base64.encode(endRegex)
       }
    });
}

/**

*

*  Base64 encode / decode

*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/

**/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
      var i = 0;

      input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

      while (i < input.length) {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
          enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
          enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

      }

      return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3;
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
      var i = 0;

      input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

      while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

      }

      output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

      return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
      string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
      var utftext = "";

      for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

        if (c < 128) {
          utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
          utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
          utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
          utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
          utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
          utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }

      }

      return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
      var string = "";
      var i = 0;
      var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

      while ( i < utftext.length ) {

        c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

        if (c < 128) {
          string += String.fromCharCode(c);
          i++;
        }
        else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
          c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
          string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
          i += 2;
        }
        else {
          c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
          c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
          string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
          i += 3;
        }

      }

      return string;
    }

  }
```

I also used this code on PHP side to turn off magic quotes:

```
<?php

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}

if (isset($_POST['startRegex'])) {
    $startRegex = base64_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "startRegex"));
}

echo $startRegex;  //Output: "d+-d+-d+Td+:d+:d++d+:d+sINFOs(d):sSTARTEsKundenimport"
```

But I get this output: `"d+-d+-d+Td+:d+:d++d+:d+sINFOs(d):sSTARTEsKundenimport"`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try using \\\ instead of \

Comment: @wayneOS, ok this worked, thx! But I wonder why I even have to do this? And is there a better way than to mess with the regex like this?

Comment: You do not mess with it. It is just so that a backslash is an escape-char. so if you want to send them as "text" you need to escape them and also escape the escaping backslash. therefore 3 times.

Comment: But it is fact that I have to mess with it. I think I will just write a simple funciton which replaces \ with \\\

Comment: Do as u please. But remember that you will have to even further escape those backslashes in your replace-function. Something like \\\\\\\\\ could be nesaccery. good luck! ;)

Comment: Why is this even needed? Is `\\` a special char which is needed for http?